# Acquit or remit?

Tags: word-usage

According to Oxford dictionaries' definitions acquit(free (someone) from a criminal charge by a verdict of not guilty) and remit(cancel or refrain from exacting or inflicting (a debt or punishment)) are nearly synonymous. 
But on a graph in "the Hindu", persons 
with criminal charges acquitted and remitted were shown  separately. 
So, is there any difference?

Comment: I cannot think of a sense in which they are in any way synonymous. The only sense of "remit" I can find relating to a case in the OED is " (_Law_) to send back (a case) to a lower court", and no meaning of "acquit" relating to cases (a _defendant_ may be acquitted in a prosecution, but the case is not acquitted). I can only guess that this relates to meanings of the words specific to Indian English. Perhaps if you gave some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not synonymous. They are both used in law but mean very different things, even though the outcome of both may seem similar.

> Acquit means "to free (someone) from a criminal charge **by a verdict of not guilty**".

So accused goes to court for the first time to be tried for charges and they are *acquitted*, meaning they are found not to be guilty in the first instance.

> Remit means "to **cancel** or refrain from exacting or inflicting (a debt or punishment)"

You can only "cancel" something that has already been put in place, so this describes a situation where the accused *has* been found guilty but the prescribed punishment is then cancelled or not carried out.